# Is the behavior of "a=(b+n)/++n" defined?

Tags: c++

I am wondering if following expression has defined behavior (always equal to "`a=n/(n+1); ++n;`") in C++?

```
a=n/++n;
```

Comment: Unless this is for academic purposes, why would you want to write something that is difficult or ambiguous to understand ?

Comment: See [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/).

Comment: Voted to reopen to close as dupe of @outis' linked question.

Answer (score 3):

It's undefined. You cannot both modify and access a variable without either having an intervening sequence point or using a single access/modify operator.